# code of website's navigation (about columns and rows)

Tags: html, css, html-table, navigation

I'm writing to leave a question about my code while I'm coding.

I'm working on transferring the navigation design of the website to the code. If you look at the website navigation layout design attached as an image, there are 10 rows and 8 columns. So I wrote the code like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/czdxy.jpg)

What I think is the problem is that without any text, the height setting value of 10% is not reflected. I would like to ask for your help on where and how to fix this.

In addition, I'm not a coding expert, so if you could answer me with a specific code test, I'd really appreciate it.

Thank you for your help in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {margin-top: 0; margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0;}

  /* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
  .column {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 10%/* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  }

  .logo {
    float: left;
    width: 12.5%;
    padding: 0;
    height: 20%/* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  }

  .column2 {
    float: right;
    width: 87.5%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 10%; /* Should be removed. Only for demonstration */
  }

  /* Clear floats after the columns */
  .row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
</style>
</head>


<body>

  <div class="row">

    <div class="logo" style="background-color:#aaa;">
      <h2>Column 1</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#bbb;">
      <h2>Column 2</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ccc;">
      <h2>Column 3</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Column 4</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Column 5</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Column 6</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Column 7</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Column 8</h2>
    </div>

    <div class="column2" style="background-color:#ddd;">
      <h2>Column 8</h2>
    </div>

  </div> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can use CSS [grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). So I recomment to follow attached link for comprehensive guide to CSS grid.

This is an example of using grid.
NOTE: I have change your `HTML` structure.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
}

header {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 7fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "logo nav" "logo notice";
}

.logo {
  background: red;
  grid-area: logo;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  grid-area: nav;
}

.notice {
  background: blue;
  grid-area: notice;
  padding: 10px;
}

nav a {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px dashed gray;
  text-align: center;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(8, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(8, 1fr);
}

main>div {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px dashed gray;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed gray;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <header>
      <div class="logo">Logo</div>
      <nav>
        <a href="#">About</a>
        <a href="#">Exibition</a>
        <a href="#">Shop</a>
        <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="#">&nbsp;</a>
        <a href="#">En</a>
      </nav>
      <div class="notice">Space for Notice</div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <!-- First Row -->
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
      <div>D</div>
      <div>E</div>
      <div>F</div>
      <div>G</div>
      <div>H</div>

      <!-- Second Row -->
      <div>A</div>
      <div>B</div>
      <div>C</div>
      <div>D</div>
      <div>E</div>
      <div>F</div>
      <div>G</div>
      <div>H</div>

      <!-- Other Rows Upto 8 -->
    </main </div>
```

Comment: Dont forget to accept answer, it will help for others as well